# How can we allow SharePoint 2019 OneDrive to sync outside of intranet?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, onedrive

I want to **sync SharePoint 2019 site library** to local file system via **OneDrive** using Sync option of SharePoint library and **User should be able to sync outside of intranet**.

I have setup the configuration as per [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/configure-syncing-with-the-onedrive-sync-app).

One drive work find and I can able to access my site and one drive using web browser outside of intranet. How ever when I tried to sync folder it's open OneDrive popup to login then it not able to login.

After Click on sync button it will open this window
[image: After Click on sync button it will open this window]

After click on sign in it will fail

[image: After click on sign in it will fail]

It will work fine in intranet network and after click sign in it will open window popup to ask credential. Once sign in I was able to sync.